# For a task that searches for an image artifact within a picture, can existing tools can be used or do I need to design the process myself?

Tags: neural-networks, image-recognition, ai-basics, pattern-recognition

I am familiar only with basic AI/NN concepts but never worked with any libraries/tools as tensor flow. Currently, I have a task for which AI might be ideal: detection of a certain image artifact in a picture (lets say I want to detect a black circular spot of a variable size). Because the spot can be very small or very large, I guess the NN would have to somehow process the whole picture and then proceed in smaller regions? Anyway, for such a task, do I need to learn more about machine learning or there are already tools that I could simply train (e.g. providing "clear" and "stained" image samples in their training sets) without worrying about internal details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For detecting something like a circle, or other geometric shapes, modern machine learning may be a bit overkill.

You should look at Haar Cascades, which you can find implemented in OpenCV. These are the reason cameras have been able to detect faces since the early naughts; They are efficient and easy to train; They are trained by providing positive and negative examples. They also scale better than something like a convolutional neural network; The implementation in OpenCV is made specifically to be able to detect objects of different sizes.

Here is [OpenCVs tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d28/tutorial_cascade_classifier.html) to get started.

---

This, of course, assumes that the artifact is of a known geometric shape. If not, you'll probably have to look at convolutional neural networks and anomaly detecting autoencoders.

Object detection with neural networks is generally done with RCNNs; These break up the image into regions using various methods and do object detection on these regions. The most popular algorithm in this family is probably [YOLO](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5), which learns how to break up the image. Many other approaches exist.

Comment: Thank you! I will certainly look into Haar Cascades and YOLO, as you advised. In general, do I need to study some theory or these can be used directly (configured and fed data)?

Comment: @JohnV Both have open implementations; So, you can find tutorials online on how to train Cascade classifiers and YOLO using OpenCV and Yolov5, respectively; Follow the links in my answer. Both contain tutorials.